# Special auto-completion behaviour for NSComboBox

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, autocomplete, nscombobox

I have an `NSComboBox` containing several items. If the user types while the list is open, I would like to select the appropriate item *within the list* (if there is a corresponding item).

The twist: The string in the text field is not necessarily equal to the corresponding item in the list. (The strings *within the list* may e.g. contain additional explanations.)

I tried implementing `textDidChange`:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString* nsstring = [self stringValue];
    [self selectItemAtIndex: [self findCorrespondingIndex: nsstring]]; // changes text - even if documentation states that it "does not alter the contents of the combo box’s text field"
}
```

But, contrary to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscombobox/1436735-selectitematindex), `selectItemAtIndex` changes the text in the text field, so I tried the following:

```
- (void)textDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSString* nsstring = [self stringValue];
    [self selectItemAtIndex: [self findCorrespondingIndex: nsstring]]; // changes text - even if documentation states that it "does not alter the contents of the combo box’s text field"
    [self setStringValue:nsstring]; // clears selection
}
```

But, contrary to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ComboBox/Tasks/SettingComboBoxValue.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000256-CJBBCJBH), `setStringValue` clears the selection.

Is this behavior expected?

Comment: Just an idea: use a datasource and call `findCorrespondingIndex:` in `indexOfItemWithStringValue:`.

Comment: @Willeke That's actually what I am researching right now.